# Get the value from url using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next situation in my react js application. I have 3 pages, one of the page is Login page:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Redirect, useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Login() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is Login Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The URL of this page is next `my-site/login`.
This is the default page where the users are redirected when access my site. Users can be redirected from different platform like social sites, another site where exists a link to my site. 
Issue: When for example user access from another  platform the link `my-site/admin/edit`, the user will be redirected on my site `my-site/login`. On this page i want to get the link `my-site/admin/edit` and to save it, but if i try get the link with `useLocation()` i get just only `my-site/login`, but i need to get somehow the link `my-site/admin/edit` on login page. 
Question: How to do this? Who knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you want to redirect the user to my-site/admin/edit after he/she logs in and then need to get the link my-site/admin/edit.
There are many ways to get value from url. You can use React-router dom for this.
Where you can set the path using `<Route path="my-site/:value" />`

and get the value in the props by `props.match.params.value`.
This will help - [react-router-documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params).

Comment: if i click on the link `my-site/admin/edit` from another site, and i am redirected to `my-site/login`, i am able to access the   `my-site/admin/edit` on the login page?

Comment: ok, i probably did not understand the question. Pavloav Serhiy has answered the correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state object in your redirect component to save the initial location:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    state: { referrer: currentLocation }
  }}
/>
```